# How can I automate the production and use of a matrix with an arbitrary number of dimensions in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to be able to give a program two numbers "n" and "m" and have it generate an n x n x n ... {m times} matrix. For now it works if just the [i][j][k]th element is {[i,j,k]} as long as it can be automatically generalized (e.g. to {i,j,k,l}) to arbitrary dimensions. I've tried poking numpy with a stick and hoping for the best but not much has come out of it. I think the solution is something to do with np.meshgrid but honestly I'm lost.

The actual code I've written below is as follows. So far, I have been able to generate a two-dimensional matrix where each first-order array contains each of the boundaries that I want to be able to pair with every combination of elements in all the other first-order arrays:

```
#Matrix logic
#Converts an mxn matrix to an nxm matrix
def convertMatrixMnnm(mat):
    output = []
    for j in range(len(mat[0])):
        r = []
        for k in range(len(mat)):
            r.append(mat[k][j])
        output.append(r)
    return(output)
import numpy as np
d = 2
domain = [[0,27],[0,1]]
nBoxes = 81

#Magic Box
yDataMBMatrix = []

#The first box
zeroBox = []
boxWidth = []
for j in range(len(domain)):
    zeroBox.append([domain[j][0], domain[j][0] + (domain[j][1] - domain[j][0])/nBoxes**
```

(1/d)])
boxWidth.append((domain[j][1] - domain[j][0])/nBoxes**(1/d))

```
#Box generator

#The vertices of every box
boxVertices = []
for j in range(d):
    boxVertices.append(np.linspace(domain[j][0], domain[j][1], int(nBoxes**(1/d))))

#Picks a random point within inputDomain
def generateRandomPoint(inputDomain):
    x = []
    for j in range(len(inputDomain)):
        x.append(r.uniform(inputDomain[j][0],inputDomain[j][1]))
    return(x)

#Box boundaries
boxBoundaries = []
for j in range(len(boxVertices)):
    row = []
    for k in range(len(boxVertices[j])-1):
        row.append([boxVertices[j][k], boxVertices[j][k+1]])
    boxBoundaries.append(row)
```

The context of the code is that I'm trying to develop a new stochastic optimizer, if that helps. Thanks in advance!

Update: A commenter said to add an example of the desired output. So, for example, if I told it n = 2 and m = 2, I'd like:

```
[[[0,0],[0,1]],
[[1,0],[1,1]]]
```

n = 1 and m = 3 would be

```
[[0],
[0],
[0]]
```

n = 3, m = 1:

```
[[0,1,2]]
```

n = 3, m = 3:

```
[[[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,2]],
[[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[0,1,2]],
[[0,2,0],[0,2,1],[0,2,2]]]
[[[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,0,2]],
[[1,1,0],[1,1,1],[1,1,2]],
[[1,2,0],[1,2,1],[1,2,2]]],
[[[2,0,0],[2,0,1],[2,0,2]],
[[2,1,0],[2,1,1],[2,1,2]],
[[2,2,0],[2,2,1],[2,2,2]]]]
```

Comment: Hi! Can you provide an example of the output you want?

Comment: I'll add that now

Answer (score 2):

You could generate the values with `intertools.product`, and then reshape them as arrays.

```
In [2]: import itertools
```

With your `n` as the `range` and `m` as the repeats, `product` produces:

```
In [6]: list(itertools.product(range(2),repeat=2))
Out[6]: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```

That's a total of 8 values which can be turned into a (2,2,2) array:

```
In [8]: np.reshape(list(itertools.product(range(2),repeat=2)),(2,2,2))
Out[8]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 1]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 1]]])
```

Similarly for your other examples:

```
In [9]: np.reshape(list(itertools.product(range(1),repeat=3)),(3,1))
Out[9]: 
array([[0],
       [0],
       [0]])
```

The `3,3` case needs a 4d reshape to handle 3**4 elements:

```
In [12]: np.reshape(list(itertools.product(range(3),repeat=3)),(3,3,3,3))
Out[12]: 
array([[[[0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1],
         [0, 0, 2]],

        ...
        [[2, 2, 0],
         [2, 2, 1],
         [2, 2, 2]]]])
```

Plugging your `n`, `m` into the `product` call is easy.  Deciding on the reshape will take a bit more tuple (or list) fiddling, since in some cases you want a 2d array, others 3 or 4d.  I think you can work out those details.

`np.mgrid` can also generate the values, but rearranging them as you want will take some sort of transposing.

```
In [31]: np.mgrid[:2,:2]
Out[31]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 1]],

       [[0, 1],
        [0, 1]]])

In [32]: np.mgrid[:1,:1,:1]
Out[32]: 
array([[[[0]]],


       [[[0]]],


       [[[0]]]])

In [33]: np.mgrid[:3]
Out[33]: array([0, 1, 2])

In [34]: np.mgrid[:3,:3,:3]
Out[34]: 
array([[[[0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0]],

         ....
        [[0, 1, 2],
         [0, 1, 2],
         [0, 1, 2]]]])
```